# Delete fixtures after load using Fixtures

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, testing, functional-testing

I'm working in some tests for my code and I get my first "STOP" since I don't know how to mover forward on this. See in my `setUp()` function I load fixtures:

```
public function setUp() {
    static::$kernel = static::createKernel();
    static::$kernel->boot();
    $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $this->user = $this->createUser();

    $fix = new MetaDetailGroupFixtures();
    $fix->load($this->em);

    parent::setUp();
}
```

But then I have remove that created data since I have a test for the bad case (when not entities are returned):

```
public function testListMetaDetailGroupFailAction() {
    $client = static::createClient();
    $this->logIn($client, $this->user);

    $route = $client->getContainer()->get('router')->generate('meta-detail-group-list', array('parent_id' => 20000), false);
    $client->request("GET", $route);

    $decoded = json_decode($client->getResponse()->getContent(), true);

    $this->assertCount(0, $decoded['entities']);
    $this->assertArrayHasKey('success', $decoded);
    $this->assertJsonStringEqualsJsonString(json_encode(array("success" => false, "message" => "No existen grupos de metadetalles de productos creados")), $client->getResponse()->getContent());
    $this->assertSame(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    $this->assertSame('application/json', $client->getResponse()->headers->get('Content-Type'));
    $this->assertNotEmpty($client->getResponse()->getContent());
}
```

Since records are created in setup and they remain in DB that test fail. Any advice on this? How did yours solve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no easy way to do what you ask. What is normally done is truncating the database before and after executing your tests so you have a truly clean and isolated environment.

Quoting from this nice article (http://blog.sznapka.pl/fully-isolated-tests-in-symfony2/:

```
public function setUp()
{
    $kernel = new \AppKernel("test", true);
    $kernel->boot();
    $this->_application = new \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application($kernel);
    $this->_application->setAutoExit(false);
    $this->runConsole("doctrine:schema:drop", array("--force" => true));
    $this->runConsole("doctrine:schema:create");
    $this->runConsole("doctrine:fixtures:load", array("--fixtures" => __DIR__ . "/../DataFixtures"));
}
```

As you can see, this solution makes use of Doctrine's Symfony2 commands in order to achieve the isolation state. There is a bundle I like to use which solves exactly this problem and let you use nice ready to use FunctionalTest base classes and many other features. Check it out:

https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle